# Get all currently playing sounds (or get number of playing sounds for buffer)

Tags: audio, buffer, openal

I need to erase not playing buffer. For this I must check that there are no currently playing sounds attached to the buffer.

I took a look at alGetSourcei (source, AL_SOURCE_STATE, &state) and alGetSourcei (source, AL_BUFFER, &buffer), but I need also list of all "alive" sources. Is it possible? Or is there alternative solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is your responsibility to manage the buffers and know which are in-use and which are not, I believe.